# How to align HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I use the following code for creating tables in HTML, but the year and month controls display one by one (up and down):

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name
            </th>
            <th>Sex
            </th>

            <th>Age
            </th>
            <th>Experience
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id='Name' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='Sex' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='Age' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id='years' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Year(s)
                <input id='months' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Month(s)
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I need the output like:

> [image]

But it will appear like:

> [image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is this a table of exactly? Tables shouldn't be used for layout; they should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: Although tables were commonly used to lay out forms in the past...it's not considered (AFAIK) best practice now. There are much better, and more flexible, ways of doing form layout these days.

Answer (score 1):

Adding CSS `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent the in-line nodes break into new line.

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <input id='years' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Year(s)
  <input id='months' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Month(s)
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add labels

```
 <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Sex
        </th>

        <th>Age
        </th>

        <th>Experience
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id='Name' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='Sex' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id='Age' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="">Year(s)</label>
            <input id='years' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
            <label for="">Month(s)</label>
            <input id='months' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have checked your code on different browsers. It matches with your required output.

If still facing the issue then 
I believe that you can increase the width size.

```
<td  width="">
        <input id='years' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Year(s)
        <input id='months' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Month(s)
 </td>
```

Else

Please check CSS  you have used Table or tr or td tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label><br>
            <input id='Name' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Sex</label><br>
            <input id='Sex' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
             <label>Age</label><br>
            <input id='Age' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />
        </td>
        <td>
             <label>Years</label><br>
            <input id='years' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Year(s)<br>
            <label>Months</label><br>
            <input id='months' type='text' style='width: 120px;' />Month(s)
        </td>
    </tr>
```